# How do I read in all files including subfolders when streaming from folder using spark streaming in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have some files that I want to stream using spark structured streaming. The structure is something like this:

```
myFolder
└── subFolderOne
    ├── fileOne.gz
    ├── fileTwo.gz
    └── fileThree.gz
└── subFolderTwo
    ├── fileFour.gz
    ├── fileFive.gz
    ├── fileSix.gz
```

When i only do the following, it works:

```
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("json")
  .schema(schema)
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
  .json("/myFolder/subFolderOne/")     <-------
```

but I want to read it at the root level: `/myFolder/` so that it picks all files within any number of sub folders. Is this possible?

I am using **spark 2.4.5** and **scala 2.11.6**

Comment: @blackbishop - I understand that Spark 3.0 provides an option recursiveFileLookup but there must be a better way than listing all files. I have thousands of files inside many sub folders.

Comment: @blackbishop found  a way with wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out to be as simple as this:

Before:

```
.json("/myFolder/")
```

After

```
.json("/myFolder/*")
```

Comment: Its worked perfectly. Thank you! I used with load : .load("/myFolder/*")